Interconnecting stdout and stdin between two programs
There are two programs first and second. I need to redirect stdout of first to stdin of second and stdout of second to stdin of first.

You can use named pipes (FIFOs) in Unix-like operating systems.
mkfifo pipe1 pipe2

So, we want the first program to read from pipe2 and to write to pipe1.
And the second program to read from pipe1 and to write to pipe2.
example of first.sh:
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  echo "First got: $line"
  sleep 1
done

example of second.sh:
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  echo "Second got: $line"
  sleep 1
done

how to run the scripts :
./first < pipe2 > pipe1 &

./second < pipe1 > pipe2 &


You could probably do this with one named pipe and one Shell pipe, although a symmetrical solution is more satisfying. I cannot visualise whether this would eventually deadlock in a real situation (for example if the messages varied in length significantly, or the timing was irregular).
